# Replacing zero and one in data frame in R with letters

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) which looks like this:

```
     df$a df$b       
      T   C          1          1          1          1          
      A   G          0          1          1          0          
      C   G          0          0          1          1          
      A   T          0          0          0          0
```

I would like to have this output:

```
      T   C          C          C          C          C          
      A   G          A          G          G          A          
      C   G          C          C          G          G          
      A   T          A          A          A          A
```

Basically if it is zero it takes the letter in column df$a while if it is 1 it takes the letter in column df$b and the zeros and ones are replaced.

Anybody knows how to do this in R?

Comment: It is unclear what structure your data has, but you could use something like `ifelse(indicator, df$b, df$a)` where `indicator` is the matrix of 1/0 indicators (which R will interpret as 0=FALSE, 1=TRUE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with base functionality - note that I read the data in columns 1 and 2 as characters, not factors.

```r
df <- read.table(text = "       
      T   C          1          1          1          1          
                 A   G          0          1          1          0          
                 C   G          0          0          1          1          
                 A   T          0          0          0          0", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[, 3:ncol(df)] <- sapply(df[, 3:ncol(df)], function(x) ifelse(x == 1, df[, 2], df[, 1]))
df
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#> 1  T  C  C  C  C  C
#> 2  A  G  A  G  G  A
#> 3  C  G  C  C  G  G
#> 4  A  T  A  A  A  A
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
df[, -(1:2)] <- ifelse(df[, -(1:2)] == 1, df[, 2], df[, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution.

```
df[-(1:2)] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  y <- as.numeric(x[-(1:2)])
  x[1:2][y + 1]
}))

df
#  a b c d e f
#1 T C C C C C
#2 A G A G G A
#3 C G C C G G
#4 A T A A A A
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
a   b          c          d          e          f
T   C          1          1          1          1          
A   G          0          1          1          0          
C   G          0          0          1          1          
A   T          0          0          0          0   
", header = TRUE)
```